# Scala: IOException during execute sh file

Tags: scala, sh

I'm trying to execute sh-file from resources.

Executed file is located at the root of resources:  src/main/resources/hiveCommand.sh

```
import sys.process._
"./hiveCommand.sh" !!
```

But receive IOException: not such file or directory

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Current directory of a build system or a compiled program can be (and usually is) different than the directory a particular file. Also the final program would probably be put into JAR or docker image, so file inside `resources` will almost certainly not in the same directory as directory from which final program would be run.

Comment: Considering that, is it better to read file from resources (using Source, for example), define absolute path of retrieven file and use this absolute path to execute sh-file?

Comment: If your file will be inside the JAR resources shell will have no access to it, so you'd have to read it from resources, write to some /tmp location, give it execution rights and then call. Does it even has to be there? You could store scripts outside `src` and pass through e.g. environment variable or command line option the location of script directory.

Comment: Mateusz, I located sh-file at hdfs-directory, where my JAR is located. But result is the same...

Comment: `println(sys.props("user.dir"))`. I think you'll find out that the value is different than where JARs and scripts are placed.

Comment: You are right! The paths are different! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Scala's Process integration does not know how to handle shell scripts. It can only start programs. To run a shell script you need start a shell (e.g. `bash`) and give it the file to run as an argument.

There is a complication however. Since the script is a resource (located at `src/main/resources/hiveCommand.sh` during compile time), it is located in a jar at run time.

So in short:

- First extract the shell script (use `getClass.getResourceAsStream("/hiveCommand.sh")` to read the resource) and store it on disk.
- Then start with something like:

  ```scala
  "bash /tmp/hiveCommand.sh".!!
  ```